# HDFS Directory with '.' in the name

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I accidentally created a directory in HDFS that is named 'again.' and I am trying to delete the directory.  I have tried everything that I can think to help but, have been unsuccessful.  I tried 'hdfs dfs -rm -r /user/[username]/*'.  I tried 'hdfs dfs -rm -r '/user/[username]/again.'.  None of these have worked !  Even the first which deleted every directory except for the directory that I wanted to delete.

Hadoop 2.7.3

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a `?` placeholder:

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r /user/[username]/again?
```

That could theoretically match other files too, but if you have only one matching file it should work tolerably well.

Comment: Is that a bash thing? If so, I don't think that'll be translate to a hdfs path

Comment: I don't actually know if it would work with another filesystem; I've only ever seen it with hdfs.

Comment: Hmm. I've never seen this documented anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r "/user/[username]/again\."
```

or

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r ".\ /user/[username]/again\."
```

Note: In case you have Hue, please do it in Hue. That will make life easy.

Answer (score 0):

None of the responses worked but, thank you all for responding.  I just dropped the entire directory structure and refreshed the environment from an existing instance.